# React Start Script Does Not Open in Firefox

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-scripts, npm-start, npx

When I start a new react app using `npx create-react-app some-app` and then adjust the start script to `"start": "BROWSER='Firefox Developer Edition' react-scripts start"`, it still opens up with chrome when I run with `npm start`. What am I missing?

Here's the github: https://github.com/yanichik/react-course/tree/main/full-course/practice/some-app

Here's my package.json file:

```
{
"name": "some-app",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.3"
},
"scripts": {
    "start": "BROWSER='Firefox Developer Edition' react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
        "react-app",
        "react-app/jest"
    ]
},
"browserslist": {
    "production": [
        ">0.2%",
        "not dead",
        "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
        "last 1 chrome version",
        "last 1 firefox version",
        "last 1 safari version"
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: When I change from react-scripts v5.0.0 to v4.0.3, the script opens Firefox as intended. Is there something wrong with v5.0.0 OR is there something else that needs to be done?